# separate attribute from name products (Odoo 14)

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-14

sorry my english. I need a help with a issue I have. I defined a funtion to bring values attributes products however, when I run it, the result is

```
ValueError: Expected singleton: product.template.attribute.value(9, 25)
```

will somebody guide me to solve it? I dont know how to go on

```
class MRPSalesProduc(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'mrp.production'

    product_short_name = fields.Char('Productos')

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        product_short_name = self.env['sale.order'].search([('name', '=', vals[
            'origin'])]).order_line.product_id.product_template_attribute_value.attribute_id
        vals['product_short_name'] = product_short_nam
        rec = super(MRPSalesProduc, self).create(vals)
        return rec
```

Comment: You already have a `product_id` field in ``mrp.production``, you can use that field to compute the new product name without attribute names.

Comment: Hi Kenly! I am not sure about you said. What I need are the attribute values, i mean, in one col I need a product name and in other col the atribute value.
eg. I my product is 
|Chair (White) |   i need to have..

| Chair | white |

Comment: `order_line` is a `One2many` field and `product_template_attribute_value_ids` is a `Many2many` field, you need to loop over the record set  (`<product.template.attribute.value(9, 25)>`) to get values.

Comment: Did you succeed to separate the product attributes?

Comment: Hi Kenly, there is no way for mi. I am still trying to get it I am stuck. I have the field product_id as you said in mrp.production. And how can I separe it? how can I loop over?

Comment: yes Kenly, I have defined in ```mrp.production``` a field ```products_name``` insted of ```product_name```, I forgot "s". Now, my question would be if the logic above is right or I am making mistakes. Thank you so much for your huge patience. I know it is so basic for you but I am lerning slowly when I get out from my job I see videos to understand more about odoo

Comment: Try to avoid overriding the create method, you need to get the product name in MRP production which is related to the product name which is also related to the product template name. Related fields are created to meet this need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [related](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/reference/orm.html#related-fields) many2many field to get product attributes

***Example:***

```py
class MRPSalesProduct(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'mrp.production'

    product_template_attribute_value_ids = fields.Many2many(related='product_id.product_template_attribute_value_ids')
```

Then use the `man2many_tags` widget to show the product attributes as tags:

```xml
<field name="product_template_attribute_value_ids" widget="many2many_tags"/>
```

***Example (Product name):***

```py
class MRPProductsName(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'mrp.production'

    products_name = fields.Char(related="product_id.product_tmpl_id.name", string='Productos')
```

Comment: I did not know mapped, that is great, Kenly. However i would need to separate the values, eg: | Table |  white | Paraiso 
where "Table" is my product and my attributes are "color" and "type". As you show me, the result gives me | white paraiso| and y need for one hand "white" and the other hand "paraiso" I mea, I think I will need two fields. Field "Color" and "Type". Do you understand me? sorry for my english, Kenly and I appreciate your politness

Comment: Kenly, could you see the problem? I mean, how to separate the values attributes?

Comment: Sorry to reply too late. Your question title says ``separate product attributes from product name`` and in your example you added one fields to hold a product attribute. To implement the logic in your first comment above you will need to add as many fields as there are attributes which is not the correct way to show product attributes next to the product name. Otherwise, you can add a related ``Many2many`` field to show the product attributes as tags.

Comment: Kenly, good morning. I have a question. May I use the code you teach me to get only the name of product? without attribute? eg: my product is

Chair ( Black  , Lustrada) and I want to get only Chair.

Can I use the same code?

Comment: Yes of course, you can use the same logic and define a related `Char` field. `product_name = fields.Char(related="product_id.product_tmpl_id.name")`

Comment: Great Kenly! Could it be like this?  
```class MRPProductsName(models.Model):```  
```_inherit = 'mrp.production'```  
```products_name = fields.Char('Productos')```  
```@api.model_create_multi``` 
```def create(self, vals_list):```  
```res = super(MRPProductsName, self).create(vals_list)```  
```for prod in res:```  
```prod.products_name = fields.Char(related="product_id.product_tmpl_id.name")```  
```return res```

Comment: `fields.Char(related="product_id.product_tmpl_id.name")` will return `None.None` and you do not need to assign that value to `products_name`. In my comment above I suggested to you to declare a new field (or replace an existing one) and set the `related` attribute to `"product_id.product_tmpl_id.name"`. Check my answer

Comment: Kenly! thank you so so much!! i get it as you tought me

as you wrote above, it works!! 

  ```class MRPProductsName(models.Model):```
        ```_inherit = 'mrp.production'```

        ```products_name = fields.Char(related="product_id.product_tmpl_id.name", string='Productossss')``` you are awesome!!

Answer (score 0):

You have tried to search sale order and access all sale order lines.

If you pick first line from the sale order line, then it will be work as per your expectation. For example,

```
sale_order = self.env['sale.order'].search([('name', '=', vals['origin'])])
product_short_name = sale_order and sale_order.order_line[0].product_id.product_template_attribute_value.attribute_id

if product_short_name:
    vals['product_short_name'] = product_short_nam
```

Comment: Hello Bhavesh, in first place thank you for your time. Well, I tried the way you said but I doesn't work and I do not know what I am doing wrong. Did you say I can acces all sale order lines, rigth? when you wrote sale_order.order_line[0],  the value [0] means the number of line?? I need to get the attribute values but I did not get it. Again thank you for your time!
Regards

Comment: Yes. [0] means it will pick first line from the sale order line in whatever order comes in sale_order.order_line. If you want to set product default code in to it, you can go upto sale_order.order_line[0].product_id.default_code. In above answer, we chime in to so line->product->attribute->value